# The difference between makefile, Makefile, GNUmakefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When learning GNU make, the article from website recommends to use file named Makefile instead of makefile or GNUmakefile. But I don't know why.

And I get the following content from 'GNU make' manual:
We recommend Makefile because it appears prominently near the beginning of a directory listing, right near other important files such as README.

But I don't understand the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Each of those three will be searched for by default. You could also call it `my-grandma-said` then just pass it as an argument. But there is a defacto standard and that is `Makefile`. If you go looking through open source you’ll find it the most often.

Comment: This is not strictly true; if several of the permitted default names are present, there is a preference hierarchy. The proposed duplicate has more details.

Comment: That is why I specified defacto to delineate from dejure, but I appreciate the clarification nevertheless. Sorry for the misinfo.